# Adding CASE WHEN field IN () with jooq

Tags: jooq

How can I create a `CASE... WHEN IN (list)` condition with jooq?

I'm converting a complex order by with cases to a jooq query builder and am unable to find documentation or examples for creating `IN` conditions:

`CASE WHEN myfield IN ("val1", "val2") THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ASC,`

I can make `case... when` statements for a single value match:

```
queryBuilder.addOrderBy(case_(MYTABLE.MYFIELD)
  .when("val1", 1)
  .else_(-1).asc());
```

Comment: See again the [difference between the `<simple case>` and `<searched case>` standard SQL `CASE` expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73174525/521799)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find this solution:

```
queryBuilder.addOrderBy(DSL.decode()
    .when(MYTABLE.MYFIELD)
    .in("val1", "val2"), 1)
    .else_(-1).asc());
```