# Case when not equal in jooq

Tags: jooq

I have two case statements in an order by.

One sorts `FIELDB DESC` if `FIELDA` matches a pre-defined list of values. (Unrelated but since I see no way to replace WHEN IN ("val1", "val2"), I define each value as its own when).

```
queryBuilder.addOrderBy(case_(MYTABLE.FIELDA)
  .when("val1", MYTABLE.FIELDB)
  .when("val2", MYTABLE.FIELDB)
  .desc());
```

However, I need to sort everything that *doesn't match* those values by `FIELDB ASC`

Problem is, I can't see a way to convert this sql to jooq:

```
CASE WHEN `mytable`.`fielda` != "val1" THEN `mytable`.`fieldb` END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case_(value)` API is used to model the standard SQL `<simple case>`, not the `<searched case>`. Your expression produces:

```sql
CASE fielda WHEN val1 THEN fieldb WHEN val2 THEN fieldb END
```

It doesn't model what you seemingly intended (the `<searched case>`)

```sql
CASE WHEN fielda = val1 THEN fieldb WHEN fielda = val2 THEN fieldb END
```

Why not just use the API for the `<searched case>`, then, instead?

```java
when(MYTABLE.FIELD.ne(val1), MYTABLE.FIELDB)
```

[Both syntaxes are also documented in the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/).